# Why image is not storing in Firebase storage and URL is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

so I have 2 problems:

- So I have an object which two of the properties are storing images. I successfully stored the images in the Firebase storage and store the image name in the database. Supposed I have 2 pictures, I only got one.
- I only have the access to the image's name, but whenever I tried to print out the url it keeps on saying `nil`.

Here's some code snippet:

```
//MARK: - Make Object
func makeObjectPost(title: String, imageTitle: UIImage, content: [String: AnyObject]) {
    //Make a new post object
    let postObject = PostModel()
    postObject.title = title
    postObject.imageTitle = returningImageData(image: imageTitle)
    postObject.content = content
    //Save the new object to firebase
    postObject.save { (ref, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

makeObjectPost(title: "Third Post", imageTitle: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "william-iven-19844"), content: makeContentDict(contentPost: currPost))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that its better practice to store images with extension (.jpeg for example) in storage. 
So, when you are saving your new object to database, you store a name of image.
To get an image try to use something like this:

```
let yourImageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(withPath: "someStartingPart/images").child(yourObject.imageTitle + ".jpeg")

yourImageRef.downloadURL { (URL, error) in
    // do everything you want
}
```